# Gradle stuck downloading dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle

It has been almost two hours since I commanded gradle to refresh dependency but it seems stuck.

I am just seeing this UI:

[image]

So from the picture it seems stuck downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/jboss-parent/12/jboss-parent-12.pom but I can download the same pom file using my browser or curl in matter of seconds.

I have not configured any proxy setting for intellij or gradle; what could be the possible reason?

Comment: Looks like you're behind a proxy/firewall. I assume your company probably has an internal repository manager (line Nexus, Artifactory, or Archiva) and you have to set up your `build.gradle` to point to it. Alternatively, if you don't have an artifact repository manager on your network, you might have to manually set up the proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help @carlspring that was what I guessed but restarting intelij made the error magically disappear i will probably remove the question.